# Which License is required for accessing Managed Package objects inside Customer Community

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, customer-portal, customer-community, licenses

I have a Managed Package inside my salesforce Org. This Managed Package requires a License for Every user. manage Package has some Custom objects.

If I want to use managed Package Custom objects inside Customer Community for End users.

Do I need to have A managed package License for each and every end user, considering that managed package license is very costly.

If i have thousands of end users then what should i do.

I have checked the salesforce customer community license it doesn't mention managed package objects.

Comment: Is it just objects inside the managed package that the community users need or the package itself?

Comment: It is just objects inside managed package that needs to be exposed to community users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A managed package license and a customer community license are two distinct licenses. The former is a license that's issued by a Salesforce Partner (also referred to as an ISV) which has specific use terms that you'll want to refer to. The latter is a license issued directly by Salesforce. The objects from a managed package may or may not be accessible from within a community. Similarly, the vendor's application may or may not be supported for use in a Community by your Users. That's something you'd need to check with the vendor you've purchased the app from.

That having been said, typically one can write records to most any custom object from within a community, either custom objects the org has created, or those from a managed package. However, in the case of a managed package, you'd still need to check to see if your license allows for that.

In some cases, you might need to create a "mirror" object in the Community that allows you to pass the records from the Community into your Org via a trigger before they can finally be written to your managed package because of permissions on the object. It all depends on the kind of functionality that you need and what your license will allow.

Comment: And there are limits on the number of custom objects a community user can access though it is actually fairly easy to purchase further blocks of 10 objects for the community users.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot this answers a lot of my query but the main sticky point exist so i will try it and see my self.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavChawla, have you ever figured that one out?
Clearly, assigning a MP license for each Community user is cost prohibitive.

Comment: Hi @R.Epstein, We couldn't figure that out, so went ahead with a different solution at that time by using Mirror Object as mentioned above.