# Data in a managed package?

Tags: managed-package

Simple question, and I should know better.

If a customer uses Salesforce and installs a managed package, custom objects are installed and data gets created.

Now, suppose I want to expose some of that data to a customer within a community.

Does the vendor of the managed package have any say in whether I can do this?  Where does their say in how we use data stored on their objects end?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely expose the objects in a package to external (community) users. You just need to ensure that the org-wide defaults, CRUD permissions, etc are set to the appropriate levels so the community users can view/modify them.

[Permission Sets and Profile Settings in Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&type=0)

Also see [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141934/which-license-is-required-for-accessing-managed-package-objects-inside-customer) which covers license issues that arise around this topic.